# How can I generate buttons or fields (forms) in Flask according to a list of strings?

Tags: python, forms, flask

Well, suppose we have a list of strings (objects with a toString() method respectively) and a jinja2 template that shall have selection forms (buttons or something alike) that agree in number and label to the list. This list may alter during the session. So far, I tried to work with submit buttons and radio buttons. Problems are: submit buttons vary in size because of different string length and I dislike that radio buttons force the user to first make a choice and then submit it.

The jinja2 markup looks like this:

```
<form method = 'post' action= "{{ url_for('add_dialogue_turn') }}">
{% if questions %}
{% for q in questions %}
<input type="radio" name="question" value={{q}}> {{q}} <br>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" /><br /><br />
</form>
```

The flask function looks like this:

```
@app.route("/turn", methods=['POST'])
def add_dialogue_turn():
    label = request.form["question"]
    print(label)
    return render_template("sometemplate.html",    questions=aListOfQuestions, answers = aListOfAnswers)
```

Can I make the radio buttons submit the value directly after ticking off the circle? Or can I define some field that returns the string when clicking on it?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution within the jinja template:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<div class="sideMenuL">
  <form method = 'post' action= "{{ url_for('add_dialogue_turn') }}">
  {% if questions %}
  {% for q in questions %}
  {% autoescape false %}
    <input type="submit" name="question" value="{{q}}"><br>
  {% endautoescape %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  </form>

</div>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Front end problem. You would need either JavaScript to submit your form when a button/radio is ticked. And it also depends on how you submit your form but if you want just the data to be passed into the server without page reloading, I'd suggest Ajax. And if you just want to pass the input value into the server, you do not have to use post.

A simple example would be,

-HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="question" value={{q}} id="{{something_unique_for_each_iterable}}" onclick="submitFunction(this)">
```

-JavaScript

```
function submitFunction(event){
   id_of_radio_ticked = '#' + event.id;
   $.ajax({
     url: "{{url_for('to_your_flask_view_function')}}",
     type: 'GET',
     data: {'radio_value':$(id_of_radio_ticked).val()},
     success: function(resp){
        alert('do something with returned data')

}

});

}
```